# unquote a quoted string in zend

Tags: zend-framework

i have an text area in my form. and I am saving its value in database by quoting like this

```
$db->quote();
```

and it is saving my value in database like this ---->

```
'do recommendeee for site.\njkdc\nsdkbjvcdsjv\ndsj'
```

But on fetching its value from database , to unquote this i am using str_replace(), but its

not working, I have also tried to use `stripslashes()`, its also not working.

I don't know about the function to be used in zend to unquote a string.

Comment: Hum there is no "zend DB UNQuote" it looks like youre quoting your values twice?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the form and controller/model code. You may have a simple error or context issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just the \n character ?  Maybe you could use the PHP nl2br() function to change your \n to <br> for display.  I won't solve your problem but it might be a workaround...